# SQL Server 2005 clustered - set maximum concurrent connections to 1

Tags: sql-server-2005

On a SQL Server 2005 clustered - I set the maximum concurrent connections to 1 and now the SQL server cluster cannot start. I guess it needs at least two connections (one for each node).

Can I recover from this by restoring the master database?

Answer (score 0):

You might not have to restore the DB, try these instructions first:

1. Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
2. At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER. 
   sqlcmd.exe -E -S servername
3. When you successfully connect to the instance of SQL Server 2005, 
   execute the following Transact-SQL statements at the SQL Server prompt. 
   sp_configure 'user connections', 
   Go
   Reconfigure
   Go
4. Restart the SQL Server service for the change to take effect.

[Instructions found here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1039368-146-1.aspx)

Comment: The server is on a cluster, and the cluster is not starting because there aren't enough connections. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Maybe you could try starting the server with a minimal configuration? Like this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320728